# Is it possible to get the full path to an Android application asset file as a string?

Tags: android, filepath, assets

I'm trying to use a third party library in my Android app that only allows me to load a file using a string that represents the path to the file. I've placed this file in my app's assets folder thinking that I could use the AssetManager to get its path as a string. However, it only returns a relative path to the file. So I'm wondering if there's some way to get the full path to the file so this library can successfully load the file.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess - does `Resources.getResourceName()` do the trick?